# Using a Security Group to Manage MS SQL 2005

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, security, sql-server-2005, sql

I want to add an AD security group to my MS SQL 2005, which will contain the personal allowed to fully manage all aspects of the server.

I have created the group (DOMAIN\SQL Admins) and added it to the **Security -> Logins** list, on the server. Yet, a user, member of that group, can't connected. It gets:

**`Error number 18456, Severity 14, State 1`**

I have granted everything available on the Logins list. I have added the domain group to the local Administrators group on the server. No dice. If I add the user to the Logins list specifically (DOMAIN\user), it works.

Could anyone shed some light? I will update the questions if more information is needed.

Comment: Is it possible that you use Windows Authentication? That should conveniently resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there was an AD propagation issue. The AD Group wasn't fully propagated yet, and hence the SQL server wasn't recognizing the user as an authorized one.

Comment: Ah, yeah that would do it :)  Good point to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure they're not in another role that specifically denies access to something.
- Make sure their account is not locked

**EDIT**
Yeah, scratch those.  Just noticed it works if adding them to logins.  What version of AD are you using?  It could be the [evil Kerberos Ticket Size](http://blogs.technet.com/surama/archive/2009/04/06/kerberos-authentication-problem-with-active-directory.aspx) problem...  [Here's more](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756101.aspx) on AD limits which talks about the Kerberos ticket size.  Basically being a member of many groups whacks Kerberos authentication.  As a test remove the user from a group (few groups) and see if the SQL auth works.

Comment: Right, neither.

Answer (score 0):

Is the SQL Server and the user group in the same domain? If not, is that security group a domain local group?

Comment: Both on the same domain, correct.